# Float value stored in MySQL keeps getting messed up

Tags: mysql, floating-point, rounding

I'm trying to store float values in MySQL and my values seem to keep getting messed up. :(
I have my fields defined as `float(10,7)` and I round my values properly in PHP before inserting them:

```
$rndval = round($val,7)
INSERT INTO mytable (float) VALUES ($rndval)
```

But when I insert a value such as 47.5206797, it shows up as 47.520679**5** in my table. Why is that?

Comment: Please post how the column is defined in the table.  All "floats" in PHP should be equivalent to "double" in other languages.

Comment: as mentioned: type float(10,7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a value to be precise, store it as an exact data type such as `DECIMAL(17,7)`, which would provide the same range as `FLOAT(10,7)`.  The only down side is that the `DECIMAL` will take up more disk space than the equivilant `FLOAT`, however this is trivial compared to correcting for floating point errors where precision is a concern.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html

For more information on floating point number issues, the following may be worth a read

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: @cerr: Be aware that in `DECIMAL(10,7)`, you can store values only from `-999.9999999` up to `+999.9999999`. And depending on MySQL settings, weird things can happen if you try to store a value that won't fit in (say `1267.3`)

Comment: I guess to be strictly accurate, FLOAT(10,7) would probably require DECIMAL(17,7).  I'll remove the data storage points as I'm not confident in the numbers.  If I'm correct though the DECIMAL requires 9 bytes compared to 4 for the FLOAT.